# Viewpoint gem and Exchange resource account

Tags: ruby, rubygems, exchange-server, scheduling, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying my hand at using the Viewpoint gem (by zenchild @ github) as the base for a meeting scheduling system. It's great at reading calendar information from regular Exchange 2007 accounts, but I got stuck trying to change the SOAP request header to allow me to read resource accounts as a delegate.

I came across [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mstehle/exchange-api-team-blog-exchange-impersonation-vs-delegate-access) and it seems to indicate what I need to end up with, and I have the feeling I'm in the right place, but I'm just not quite there yet as a ruby/soap programmer. Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's something like this --


<code>
class Viewpoint::ExchangeHeaders < SOAP::Header::SimpleHandler
 NAMESPACE = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'

 def initialize
  super(XSD::QName.new(NAMESPACE,"ExchangeImpersonation"))
 end

 def on_simple_outbound
 #???
 end
end
</code>

but it's not working =\

Answer (score 1):

Scott,

I just saw your posting and I know it's a little old, but if you still need to solve your issue the upcoming version of Viewpoint has delegate access integrated into it.  You can get it today by cloning the github repo.

http://github.com/zenchild/Viewpoint

If you take a look the README file it talks about it a bit, but if you need additional help send me a message on github or stackoverflow and I'll help you out.

Cheers,

Dan